# Windows Phone 7: Is it possible to change phone accent color using a theme?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to change Theme background and Theme accent color using an application?. I wish to write a windows phone 7 app that allows users to apply a random theme.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example on how to do it: http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-01/change-accent-colors-on-windows-phone-7-samsung-devices/

Comment: The above example works only on jailbroken devices, and more over I just need the codes to choose from the existing 10 accent colors, not new ones.

Comment: do you only want to apply the different to your app or want to overwrite the existing phone theme? here is an example on how you can get the current selected theme: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545(v=vs.92).aspx You can use the default ThemeResources files that are stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design to then change it to fit it to the new selected theme, but that will only work for your app, not the device. I don't think you can change it for the device from within an app.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are after is not available.

There is no way for you to write an app (which will pass marketplace certification) which will allow you to do this.